# Message Application for Client Server

Tags: php, android, client-server

Hope you all are doing well.

I want to create an application like passing messages between Client(Android App) and Server(PHP).

There is many Clients and one Server. In my app I want to make following things:

- Send messages and images between two clients
- Client can send messages or images to server.
- Server can send messages or images to particular client

**I have think like i can send message using POST request and GET response using json.**

Is that perfect way or is there any suggestion from you?

Is there any library or links available which can help me to do this more best way..

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Send messages and images between two clients
- Server can send messages or images to particular client

  First read this : http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

JSON is a good choice: You will be able to deserialize using Jackson or Googlegson.

Use a Rest Architecture so that your server could be usable with another device(iphone,windows phone)