# DrawableLeft in a TextView using Drawable Object Programmatically

Tags: android, bitmap, textview, android-drawable

Currently developing new view for **text** and **image** [SEND/RECEIVE application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553430/message-application-for-client-server) betweeb Client and Server.

I have created `row.xml` for Row view like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/msgLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msgText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        android:background="@drawable/speech_bubble_green"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_content_picture"
        android:shadowColor="@color/textShadow"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:textSize="0sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now i want to set **drawableTop** programmatically without text when i got image to send or receive.

While sending i have picked up image from gallery and it returns **Bitmap** object.

How can i set that **Bitmap** object as `drawableTop` Programmatically.?

### P.S.

I have seen this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6932112/1318946) answer but It works for **Drawable Id.**

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following:

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
d.setBounds(0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());
textView.setCompoundDrawables(null, d, null, null);
```

Comment: +1 for that you have typed this answer, not copied. ;)

Comment: BitmapDrawable(Bitmap bitmap) constructor is deprecated.